# Visual Basic and MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, security, authentication

I need to build an application in Visual Basic 2010 to connect to a MySQL database. I saw many examples for that, but i've a question:

- should the login form be the first or the splashscreen ??
- should i check the connection before the login form appears ou after ?
- since the application it's going to be used by many people in different places should i implement a secondary authentication method to avoid the non-authorized copy of application ?

Any sugestion or help regarding this matter is appreciated.

Comment: These are decent questions, but as a whole, the post is far too broad for SO.  See [Ask].

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Do you need to inflict a splashscreen at all? If you want branding put it on the login for you would show subsequently.

Comment: If there is no expectation of the database connection being unavailable why check it before you have the details needed to perform a query on it, which is effectively doing the same thing.

Comment: I see. My main question is how the application should start: should i present a splashscreen first (and during this time, testing connections, etc...) or should i present right away the login form?

Comment: First show the Splash screen while checking the connection and and if connected put the show the login screen.   If not show a non-authorized screen. Yes implement a secondary authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a legitimate question and from experience this is how I would approach it

When launching the application I would first show the splash screen during that time I would check the connection and determine if they are connected appropriately.  If they are connected appropriately I would then show the login screen.  If not then show a non-authorized screen.  I would also implement a second authentication since your application is used by different sets of users.